# Why is this a beta distribution?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, beta-function

I'm given a circle with point $A$ defined by $(x,y)$. Then $T=1-d[O,A]$, so $T=1-\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$.

Asked to find:

1. $P[T<=u]$
2. $E[T]$
3. $Var(T)$

---

Alright, so $d[O,A]$ has the CDF $u^2$. So, for the first piece, $P[T<=u]=1-u^2$.

However, our professor has given us also the hint that $u^2$ is beta-distributed. For $Y$ that follows a beta distribution,

$$E[Y]=\frac{a}{a+b}$$
$$Var(Y)=\frac{ab}{(a+b)^2(a+b+1)}$$

So I kind of know what the answers are supposed to be, aside from the fact that I don't see how $u^2$ follows a beta distribution, so I don't know what the values $a$ and $b$ would be.

Ultimately, I think the generalized answers are:

2. $$E[T]=E[1-Y]=E[1]-E[Y]=1-\frac{a}{a+b}$$
3. $$Var(T)=Var(1-Y)=Var(T)=\frac{ab}{(a+b)^2(a+b+a)}$$

   Help uncovering the beta distribution parameters would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Some clarifications: $A$ is contained in the unit disk? $A$ is uniformly distributed? I get $P[T\le u]=P[1-u\le d(O,A)]=1-(1-u)^2$. What does "$u^2$ is beta" mean, is $u^2$ a random variable?

Comment: Since the derivative of $1-(1-u)^2$ is $2(1-u)$, you might argue that $T$ has a Beta distribution with $\alpha=1, \beta=2$

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is the unit disk. It's not specified that $A$ is uniformly distributed, but I would say that this is a fair assumption. Our professor's notation is pretty bad.

Comment: I have solved it saying that $Y$ is defined as the $u^2$ function, then saying $Y$ is distributed according to Beta with $(\alpha = 2, \beta=1)$. Then I just used linearity of expectation to get $E[T]=1/3$ and $Var(T)=1/18$. This should be equivalent t your answer, Henry. So I would agree with that - yours is more straightforward.